# ParseException when parsing a date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am running the following code:

```
DateFormat fullDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmdd/MMMyy");
Date date = fullDate.parse("035627/NOV15");
```

and the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:"035627/NOV15
```

Any ideas, why the exception is thrown, while the format is validly stated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The likeliest reason is that `NOV` is not a valid month in your default Locale. This should fix the problem (adjust the Locale to match the language used for the month name):

```
DateFormat fullDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmdd/MMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```